# javascript "include()" function not working on nashorn

Tags: javascript, nashorn

I tried to run the following javascript code on nashorn engine.

```
var fruits = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango"];
fruits.toString();
fruits.include("Orange");
```

But it gives the following error

> "TypeError: fruits.include is not a function in  at line number
>   3"

Please tell me how to fix this issue .

Comment: It's a typo use `includes` instead of `include`

Comment: what are you trying to achieve? What do you want the end result to be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not `include`, but [**includes**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes). At the end **s**.

```js
var fruits = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango"];

console.log(fruits.includes("Orange"));
```

Comment: I still get the same error. Here I run the javascript on a nashorn engine